# gmail api: replying to emails already in inbox with vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, gmail

has anyone worked with gmail with vb.net?

how do i access my inbox and find emails that were sent from a specific person and send a reply to them?

i have a list of people with whom i keep in touch with from school and since i have not replied to them in a while, i would like to feed a list of email addresses into the program that would then find emails from those people and it would reply to those emails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .Net's built-in [`SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class to send email.  To send using GMail, use the following configuration:

```
Dim smtp as New SmtpClient

smtp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("avrohom@GMail.com", "your password")
smtp.Port = 587
smtp.UseSsl = True
```

To read email, you'll need to find a .Net library for POP or IMAP; Google it.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a message with the same subject and add `RE:` to the beginning